# EF Working With One To Many Models With Composite Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn .Net Core 2.1 and testing a little project with already existing database. We have 3 tables (Template, TemplateDesc, TemplateParameter) with one of them has one-to-many relationship. When I get one Template with controller, it returns null for TemplateDescriptions and ParameterValues. Also if I try to delete Template, it returns FK exception. Can someone point the problem with the below codes?

Note : I use Swagger extension to test codes.

```
public class Template
{
    public decimal CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string TemplateCode { get; set; }
    public List<TemplateDesc> TemplateDescriptions { get; set; }
    public DateTime TemplateDate { get; set; }
    public string RuleCode { get; set; }
    public string SourceTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
    public string CreatedUserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<TemplateParameter> ParameterValues { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateDesc
{
    public decimal CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string TemplateCode { get; set; }
    public string LangCode { get; set; }
    public string TemplateDescription { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateParameter
{
    public decimal CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string TemplateCode { get; set; }
    public string TemplateRuleCode { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Template>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode });
    entity.HasMany(e => e.TemplateDescriptions).WithOne(e => e.Template).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode });
    entity.HasMany(e => e.ParameterValues).WithOne(e => e.Template).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode });
}

modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateDesc>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode, e.LangCode });
    entity.HasOne(e => e.Template).WithMany(e => e.TemplateDescriptions).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode }).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}

modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateParameter>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode, e.TemplateRuleCode, e.ParameterName});
    entity.HasOne(e => e.Template).WithMany(e => e.ParameterValues).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.CompanyCode, e.TemplateCode}).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<Template> GetWithKey([FromQuery] decimal companyCode, [FromQuery] string templateCode)
{
    try
    {
        var template = this.mRepository.Find(e => e.CompanyCode == companyCode && e.TemplateCode.AreEqual(templateCode)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (template == null)
            return new JsonResult(new ApiResponse<Template>(ResponseType.Exception, null));

        return new JsonResult(new ApiResponse<Template>(ResponseType.Success, template));
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteWithKey([FromQuery] decimal companyCode, [FromQuery] string templateCode)
{
    if (this.mRepository.Find(e => e.CompanyCode == companyCode && e.TemplateCode.AreEqual(templateCode)).Count() < 1)
        return new JsonResult(new ApiResponse<string>(ResponseType.NotFound, templateCode));

    this.mRepository.Delete(companyCode, templateCode);
    return new JsonResult(new ApiResponse<Template>(ResponseType.Success, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use lazy loading, or use Include construct:

```
db.Templates
    .Include(x => x.TemplateDesc)
    .Include(x => x.TemplateParameter)
    .FirstOrDefault(...)
```

the includes can be put in extension method:

```
public IQueryable<Template> BuildTemplate(this DbSet<Template> set)
{
  return set.Include(x => x.TemplateDesc)
        .Include(x => x.TemplateParameter);
}
```

Then you can use

```
dbContext.Templates.BuildTemplate.FirstOrdefault(x => x.TemplateDescriptions.Any(td => td.TemplateCode == "xyz"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about delete? When I try to delete Template, it returns FK exception. So I changed HasForeignKey in Template modelBuilder to have all of TemplateDesc's primary keys but this time it returns InvalidOperationException. What am I missing? I also added OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) on both lines.

Comment: You have to delete child objects also, and do it before deleting the template